# Piranha CMS HtmlRegion within Custom Region not saving content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, piranha-cms

I've created a couple of custom regions within my Piranha CMS Installation but am having problems when I have any kind of text region within my custom region. The Editor will display and you can enter text but it doesn't save to the DB.

Here's my classes

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using Piranha.Extend;
using Piranha.Extend.Regions;

namespace MatchtechGroup.Models.Regions
{
[Export(typeof(IExtension))]
[ExportMetadata("InternalId", "SimpleTab")]
[ExportMetadata("Name", "Simple Tab")]
[ExportMetadata("Type", ExtensionType.Region)]
[Serializable]
public class SimpleTab : Extension, ITab
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public HtmlRegion Tab { get; set; }

    public SimpleTab()
    {
        Tab = new HtmlRegion();
    }
}
}
```

And my Manager template in Areas/Manager/Views/Extensions

```
@model MatchtechGroup.Models.Regions.SimpleTab
@{
    Layout = "";
}
<ul class="form">
    <li>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
        <div class="input">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Tab, new { @class = "editor", @rows = 10 })
    </li>
</ul>
```

The manager interface renders my new region correctly in the page editor but will not save content from the Html Region. There are no errors displayed in the interface, I just don't get the 'This Page has saved' message bar appear or am I able to publish the page.

Any help would be much appreciated, feels like I'm missing something basic or just that I can't nest an HTML region within this custom region.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that your HtmlValue gets invalidated in the Model Binder so that Model.IsValid is false. The easiest solution to your problem is to change your property to:

```
public class SimpleTab : ...
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Tab { get; set; }
}
```

The only difference would be when using it in the Razor markup. If you had a region of the SimpleTab type called **MyTab** the syntax would then be (for example):

```
<div>
  <h3>@Model.Regions.MyTab.Title</h3>
  <div class="content">
    @Html.Raw(Model.Regions.MyTab.Tab)
  </div>
</div>
```

The only difference is `@Html.Raw()` to make sure that the body isn't escaped.

Regards

/ Håkan